# How can I have a position:sticky element of unknown height hug the top and then vertically centre on scroll?

Tags: css

Some distance down the page, I have a large (taller than the viewport) container. Inside this is a left column and a right column.

On the right is various content irrelevant to this question.

On the left is a big blank area, other than a small amount of content, which is of indeterminate height.

I want to position this small piece of content sticky, in such a way that it hugs the top of the container when this area is just coming into view (as if it were not positioned at all), then once we've scrolled enough that it's vertically in the centre of the viewport, it stays stuck to the centre. Then once we are scrolled near the bottom, it stays contained within its container.

I can get 90% of the way there just with

```
position: sticky;
top: 50%;
```

But the element is too low, because its top is 50% of the way down the viewport, whereas I want it straddling that point.

Back before we had grid and flexbox, to vertically centre something we used to do the same as above other than with `absolute`, and then add on `transform: translateY(-50%);`. I can do that here, which gets it centred nicely, but now it does not behave properly when near the top or bottom of the scroll range.

Is there any way to do this without involving JS?

```css
.irrelevant {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40% 1fr;
}

#left {
  position: relative;
}

#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="irrelevant">
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
</section>

<section id="grid">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="sticky">
      <h2>Sticky</h2>
      <p>This should all be centred in the viewport.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="irrelevant">
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
    <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="irrelevant">
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
  <p>Irrelevant content</p>
</section>
```

Comment: I think your example is working fine, can you tell me what exactly is the problem again?

Comment: The heading "Sticky" and the paragraph beneath it should all, as a group, be vertically centred in the viewport. Whereas at the moment the top point of that whole group is centred, and so it's all below-centre.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is impossible to get dynamic height of the element using only CSS.

You can use this to keep it from going out of the boundary instad of `transform: translateY(-50%);`

```
top: calc(50% - 33px); /* 33px is the half value of the rough height of the element. */
```

Comment: This would absolutely be a reasonable answer if only the height was predictable. The content is entirely dynamic, however, as is the width of the container due to the flexible viewport, and so I can't make a confident guess at half the height.